# Simple Array Sum Not Working

Tags: php

```
  function regex_scrape($regex,$results_page){
       preg_match_all($regex,$results_page,$match);
       return $match;
    }


$continue = TRUE;   
$prices = array();
$url = "";

while ($continue == TRUE) {
    $results_page = curl($url); // Downloading the results page using our curl() funtion
    $prices2 = regex_scrape('/<span class=\"h3 price-amount\">(.*)span>/',$results_page);
    $prices = array_merge($prices,$prices2[0]);
```

Array looks like this and I can't array_sum or find lowest array value (min)

```
Array ( [0] => 45 [1] => 80 [2] => 60 [3] => 40 [4] => 37 [5] => 69 [6] => 34 [7] => 79 [8] => 46 [9] => 91 [10] => 269 [11] => 59 [12] => 60 [13] => 79 [14] => 35 [15] => 67 [16] => 85 [17] => 45 )
```

`echo array_sum($prices);` Returns 0 why?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KZ8pw5md here is working example that it's not working. All the smart asses who up vote the simple solutions I have already tried don't take this seriously!

Answer (score 3):

Your example array does not have consecutive indexes (probably from the `array_merge`). Have you tried doing an `array_values` first?

```
echo array_sum(array_values($prices));
```

Comment: it seems like array_values also returns 0

Comment: @zumbamusic Then your array does not look like what you posted in your question.

Comment: @Evert `Array ( [0] => 37 [1] => 45 [2] => 34 [3] => 48 [4] => 60 [5] => 40 [6] => 30 [7] => 50 [8] => 80 [9] => 69 [10] => 42 [11] => 56 [12] => 59 [13] => 108 [14] => 41 [15] => 91 [16] => 34 [17] => 95 )` just used `print_r($prices);`

Comment: If that's true, then `print_r(array_values($prices));` _can not_ return 0.

Comment: @Evert it's, But Uours answer (var_dump) showed that it's not INT but a STRING values. I guess have to convert it somehow

Comment: @Jack @Evert check out this simple example the array returns what I showed you but `array_sum` isn't working! http://pastebin.com/KZ8pw5md

Comment: Every item in the `$match[0]` array contains a string like `<span class="h3 price-amount">52</span>`. Obviously not a number.

Answer (score 1):

If the array you've posted is the actual array your code is dealing with , I do not see any problem .

```
$prices = array ( '0' => 45 ,'1' => 80 ,'2' => 60 ,'3' => 40 ,'4' => 37 ,'5' => 69 ,'6' => 34 ,'7' => 79 ,'8' => 46 ,'9' => 91 ,'10' => 269 ,'11' => 59 ,'12' => 60 ,'13' => 79 ,'14' => 35 ,'15' => 67 ,'16' => 85 ,'17' => 45 );

var_dump( $prices );

echo array_sum( $prices );
```

The above code is giving me sum as `1280` .

Furthermore array indexes need not be consecutive :

```
$prices = array ( '100' => 45 ,'90' => 80 ,'80' => 60 ,'70' => 40 ,'4' => 37 ,'5' => 69 ,'6' => 34 ,'7' => 79 ,'8' => 46 ,'9' => 91 ,'10' => 269 ,'11' => 59 ,'12' => 60 ,'13' => 79 ,'14' => 35 ,'15' => 67 ,'16' => 85 ,'17' => 45 );

var_dump( $prices );

echo array_sum( $prices );
```

The above code also gave me a sum as  `1280` .

I did not see any issue with the array you've posted in your comment below :

```
$prices = array( 0 => "45" ,1 => "40" ,2 => "85" ,3 => "46" ,4 => "69" ,5 => "34" ,6=> "60" ,7=> "91" ,8=> "86" ,9=> "48" ,10=> "70" ,11=> "80" ,12=> "42" ,13=> "67" ,14=> "108" ,15=> "37" ,16=> "45" ,17=> "95" );

var_dump( $prices );

echo array_sum( $prices );
```

This gave a sum as `1148` .

Comment: `array(18) { [0]=> string(39) "45" [1]=> string(39) "40" [2]=> string(39) "85" [3]=> string(39) "46" [4]=> string(39) "69" [5]=> string(39) "34" [6]=> string(39) "60" [7]=> string(39) "91" [8]=> string(39) "86" [9]=> string(39) "48" [10]=> string(39) "70" [11]=> string(39) "80" [12]=> string(39) "42" [13]=> string(39) "67" [14]=> string(40) "108" [15]=> string(39) "37" [16]=> string(39) "45" [17]=> string(39) "95" } 0` var_dump will return INT for your array but string for mine

Comment: Your issue seems to be some where else . The above array is also giving me a sum as `1148` .

Comment: `array_merge` can merge one or more arrays . Are you sure `prices2[0]` is an array ? Otherwise you might want to try `$prices = array_merge( $prices ,$prices2 );`

Comment: `$prices2[0]` is coming back from my function (In my question) which is basicly `preg_match_all` as far I understand it return array. And `$prices` is manually set `array()` I'm stil also confused why its not working something isn't right

Comment: You might want to make sure by doing `var_dump( $prices2 );` .

Comment: `http://pastebin.com/K6u7iVDE` my full script for quick test I run it via `http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php` take a look.

Comment: Your `$results_page = curl( $url );` is returning `false` .

Comment: what you think can cause that?

Comment: chaning curl to `file_get_contents` also doesn't work so I don't see the curl as the issue